# How to skip over subdirectories in a for loop based on name alone?

Tags: bash

I have a directory organized into subdirectories in the manner of:

```
a1
b1
c1
c2
c3
d1
```

I'm trying to perform loop that only executes on the most recent subdirectory of a given letter, ie it would loop through `a1`, `b1`, `c3`, and `d1`, but ignore `c1` and `c2`. My efforts so far have revolved around directly trying to compare the numeric values of the subdirectory names, but that hasn't worked out very well. I'm new to bash, so apologies if this is a simple fix that I'm missing.

Comment: I see you’re new to the Stack Exchange network. Welcome!
You should edit your question to include what you've tried, what outcome you expected and what you got instead of your expected results.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to achieve your goal

```
#!/bin/bash
for DIR in {a..z}
do
 GOOD=$(find ${DIR}[0-9] -type d -print -prune 2>/dev/null | tail -1)
 if [[ "$GOOD" ]]; then
  echo $GOOD
 fi
done
```

Example usage:

```
$ mkdir a1 b1 c1 c2 c3 d1
$ ./a.sh
a1
b1
c3
d1
$
```

Comment: Is there any guarantee that `find` will return sorted output?

Comment: Yes.  The shell expands the `${DIR}[0-9]` in sorted order.  `bash` man page confirms "....and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern..."

Comment: Oh, of course! I completely missed the fact that you were using a glob. Very clever!

Comment: Note that this only works if the numerical suffix consists of a single digit (or more precisely, if all the numerical suffixes for a given prefix have the same number of digits), since `a10` will be sorted between `a1` and `a2`.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a somewhat complicated little pipeline to do your job:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d |
sed -e '/\.$/d' -e '/\.\.$/d' -e 's/\.\/\(.\)\(.\)/\1   \2/' |
sort -k1.1 -k2.1n |
awk 'BEGIN {last=""}
        {
                if (last == "") {
                        last = $1; number = $2
                } else if ($1 != last) {
                        printf "%s%s\n", last, number;
                        last = $1; number = $2
                } else {
                        number = $2
                }
        }
        END { printf "%s%s\n", last, number }
'
```

You will probably have to change the arguments to `find` to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One way to act on the last of a series is to loop over all elements, remembering the previous item. If you detect that a new series is beginning, act on the remembered previous item. Untested code. I assume that you're only interested in directories whose first character is not a dot and whose last character is a digit.

```
act_on () {
  …
}
previous_prefix=0
previous_name=
for x in *[0-9]/; do
  x=${x%/}
  digits=${x##*[!0-9]}
  prefix=${x%"$digits"}
  if [ "$prefix" != "$previous_prefix" ] && [ "$previous_prefix" != "0" ]; then
    # New prefix, so act on the previous element
    act_on "$previous_name"
  fi
  previous_prefix=$prefix
  previous_name=$x
done
act_on "$previous_name"
```

Beware that `foo9` is sorted after `foo10`. In zsh, use `*[0-9](/on)` to use numerical sorting where `9` is sorted before `10`. If you aren't using zsh, a different approach will be needed. One way is to act only on the first item of the series, but instead of acting on the item you've found, use its prefix and determine the last element of the numerical series.

```
act_on () {
  …
}
previous_prefix=0
previous_name=
for x in *[0-9]/; do
  x=${x%/}
  digits=${x##*[!0-9]}
  prefix=${x%"$digits"}
  if [ "$prefix" != "$previous_prefix" ]; then
    suffixes=
    for y in "$prefix"*; do
      suffixes="$suffixes
${y#"$prefix"}"
    done
    last_suffix=$(echo "$suffixes" | sort -n | tail -n 1)
    act_on "$prefix$last_suffix"
  fi
  previous_prefix=$prefix
  previous_name=$x
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If your directory names are as simple as you show (at least, if the don't contain whitespace or other strangeness), you could just do:

```
for d in $(ls | sort -r | rev | uniq -s1 | rev); do echo "$d"; done
```

Change the `echo "$4d"` to whatever it is your loop should be doing. However, this will fail if your directory names are not quite as you show them as it's vulnerable to all the [pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) of parsing ls. It works by first listing the directories, sorting them in reverse order, reversing them (so `a1` becomes `1a`), keeping only unique lines but ignoring the 1st character (`uniq -s1`) and re-reversing them to get the original name back.